# can you repeat through multiple types of AngularJS directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Setup: I'm learning Angular JS by re-building a dynamic survey application that I built a few years ago with .NET.  The DB has a series of a questions for any particular test and each of those questions ties to one answer type (multiple choice, free text, true/false).

In .NET, I just created an "answer" base class that the different type of answers derived from that can be provided for a question.  Then used a repeater to build and push out the html for each of those distinct types.

**Question:**  Right now, I have setup a directive for each answer type to handle the functionality/look/feel of each type of answer.  I'd like to be able to loop through a json document of question and answer types to generate the proper view but I don't know how to do that.  Should I create a question directive that contains each type of answer directive and only outputs the one that's not null or can I use ng-repeat somehow to return the proper answer directive?

Any examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then as far as I am aware, this is a bit tricky but not impossible to achieve in Angular.

If you have a data model as follows:

```
$scope.answers = [
    { dir: 'multiple-choice-answer', data: { ... } },
    { dir: 'text-answer', data: { ... } },
    { dir: 'radio-button-answer', data: { ... } }
];
```

And each directive looks something like this:

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('multipleChoiceAnswer', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        replace: true, 
        templateUrl: '<div class="multiple-choice-answer">this is a multiple choice answer</div>',

        link: function ($scope, elm, attrs) {
        }
    };

});
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in answers">
    <div {{dir}}></div>
</div>
```

Then unfortunately that will not work and not parse as you would expect. The way I managed to get around this was to create a wrapper directive as follows:

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('answerWrapper', ['$compile', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            answer: '='
        },
        replace: true,   
        template: '<div class="answer-wrapper"></div>',

        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('answer', function (val) {
                scope.build(val.dir);
            });

            scope.build = function (directiveName) {
                var answer = $compile('<div ' + directiveName + ' answer="answer"></div>')(scope);
                elm.append(answer);
            };
        }
    };

}]);
```

And then use it in the repeater as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in answers">
    <div answer-wrapper answer="answer"></div>
</div>
```

Notice in the compile string, we pass the answer object to the compiled answer type, so that it will have access to the data object in the model.

Comment: First, thanks for your response!

I actually was using what you first drew up as the unfortunate circumstance and quickly realized the unfortunateness of it all.  My next attempt was doing what you suggested, only instead of answerWrapper, I have it named "question" directive (ng-repeat="question in questions").  I think my disconnect there was that I haven't used the $compile method before, so I think that may be what I'm missing.

I will update your response as the answer if that is indeed what I was missing.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: The key was the $compile option.  In my linking function for each "question" directive, I created the answer section as you mentioned in your answer and that did the trick.